# Processing: Adding random colors to ellipse in class

Tags: processing

I'm trying to generate random colors each time a key is pressed. I took code from this example: http://learningprocessing.com/examples/chp14/example-14-18-solar-system-OOP

I've tweaked it for my own project but I'm having a hard time changing the fill each time a key is pressed. (I tried pasting it here but the formatting kept messing up, so I put it on pastebin)

Class File: https://pastebin.com/HiBXdA4A

**Main File:**

```java
boolean colorChange = false;

// An array of 8 planet objects
Planet[] planets = new Planet[30];
ArrayList<Planet> newPlanets = new ArrayList<Planet>() ;

void setup() {
  //size(900, 900);
  fullScreen();

  // The planet objects are initialized using the counter variable
  for (int i = 0; i < planets.length; i++ ) {

    planets[i] = new Planet(185 + i*5, 8);

  }

}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  /* Stars */
  randomSeed(103);

  for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
  float x = random(0, width);  
  float y = random(0, height);  

  ellipse(x, y, 2, 2);
  fill(255);
  }

  // Drawing the Earth
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  stroke(0);
  fill(0, 191, 255);
  ellipse(0,0,350,350);
  noFill() ;
  // Drawing all Planets
  for (int i = 0; i < planets.length; i++ ) {
    planets[i].update();
    planets[i].display();
  } 

   if(newPlanets.size() > 0) {
      for(int i = 0 ; i < newPlanets.size() ;i++) {
        println("newPlanets should be drawing") ;
        Planet p = newPlanets.get(i) ;
        p.update() ;
        p.display() ;
      }
    }


  popMatrix();

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  text("[Press E for Air Pollution]", width/9, height - (height/8));
  fill(255, 255, 0);
  text("[Press W for Ground Level Pollution]", width/9, height - (height/8 + 15));
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  text("[Press Q for Greenhouse Gasses]", width/9, height - (height/8 + 30));
}

void keyPressed() {
  if(key == 'q' || key == 'Q') {
      for(int i = 0 ; i < planets.length ; i++) {
        newPlanets.add(new Planet(185 + i*5, 8));
      }
  }

  if(key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
      for(int i = 0 ; i < planets.length ; i++) {
        newPlanets.add(new Planet(185 + i*5, 8)) ;
      }
  }

  if(key == 'e' || key == 'E') {
      for(int i = 0 ; i < planets.length ; i++) {
        newPlanets.add(new Planet(185 + i*5, 8));
      }
  }

}
```

**Class File:**

```java
// Example 14-18: Object-oriented solar system

class Planet {
  // Each planet object keeps track of its own angle of rotation.
  float theta;      // Rotation around sun
  float diameter;   // Size of planet
  float distance;   // Distance from sun
  float orbitspeed; // Orbit speed
  float resetingDistance ;
  color planetColor;
  boolean colorChange = false;


  Planet(float distance_, float diameter_) {
    distance = distance_;
    resetingDistance = distance_ ;
    diameter = diameter_;
    theta = 0;
    orbitspeed = random(0.01, 0.03);
    //planetColor = color( random(255), random(255), random(255), random(255));
  }

  void update() {
    // Increment the angle to rotate
    theta += orbitspeed;
  }

  void display() {
    // Before rotation and translation, the state of the matrix is saved with pushMatrix().
    pushMatrix(); 
    // Rotate orbit
    rotate(theta); 
    // Translate out distance
    translate(distance, 0); 
    stroke(0);
    fill(175);

    if (colorChange == true) {
      //fill(random(255), random(255), random(255), random(255));
      planetColor = color( random(255), random(255), random(255), random(255));
    }

    ellipse(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
    // Once the planet is drawn, the matrix is restored with popMatrix() so that the next planet is not affected.
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

Comment: So you change the "planetColor" on some condition, colorChange, but you dont seem to have change the colorChange variable, and you dont use the "planetColor" variable anywhere - unless I'm missing something.

Comment: And when you have found out how to set colorChange when a key is pressed, remember to reset the variable when the planetColor gets itsnnew value.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't just copy-paste code you find on the internet and then try to hammer away at it. You'll just give yourself a ton of headaches that way. Instead, you really need to understand exactly what each line does, and then create a new sketch and take those lessons to accomplish your goal.

You need to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take on those steps one at a time. For example, can you create a simple sketch that just shows a random color? Okay, now can you make that color change whenever the user types a key?

The basic approach you need to take is this:

- Store the color in a set of variables.
- Use those variables to draw your scene.
- Change those variables when the user takes some action.

That's the general approach, and in your case you'll probably want to store those variables in your `Planet` class so that each planet can have its own color.

Here's a small example that follows that approach to show a random color whenever the user clicks the mouse:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.6/processing.js"></script>
<script type="application/processing">

float r = 128;
float g = 128;
float b = 128;

void setup(){
   size(300, 200);
}

void draw(){
  background(r, g, b);
}

void mousePressed(){
  r = random(256);
  g = random(256);
  b = random(256);
}
</script>
<canvas> </canvas>
```

This code is just an example, but it shows how you can use the above approach to change stuff when the user takes an action. I highly recommend you start over with a simple sketch like this, and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.